# loading module and object files automatically on booting

Tags: c, module, linux-kernel, boot

I have created a module.ko and a object file a.out that uses the module.
Does someone know how I load them both on booting?

- I did `depmod` to my module and then `modprobe -a`.
- I think it damaged my system.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your distro has a configuration file to list all kernel modules that must be loaded when the system boots. Try `man 5 modules` to check how it works. Otherwise check a file named /etc/modules, or the documentation of your OS.